# How can I add in app messaging between admin and user in flutter project?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

- We were assigned a flutter project called **Event-Management** mobile app for our College - SAKEC.
- In this app, we were told that only admins and event coordinators can create-event and add to the Homepage, which is completed.
- **The part we are stuck at is Notifications/Communication between admin and user, We were told that the events created by the coordinator were to be reviewed by the Principal. If the Principal approves the created event then the event gets added to the HomePage, But if he declines, the event is deleted.**
- How can we add the communication part? The communication should be done in the form of notifications.

Comment: exactly what have your tried so far?  So user creates a event and admin reviews it?

Comment: share what you've tried. For notifications you can use FCM (https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) or MQTT (https://pub.dev/packages/mqtt_client) depending on your use case

Answer (score 0):

I am considering that you are using firebase database
so you can continue [like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTd33.png):

i) Create a node something like "NEW EVENTS" this node will contain all the new events
which are waiting for authentication

ii) Now you need to make a token system, because you need to inform principal via                                  notification, so you need to have a token system by using that you can notify a particular user ( like principal )

iii) Then push the newly created events to "NEW EVENTS" node and notify the principal using FCM

iv) Now you need to retrieve data from "[**NEW EVENTS**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTd33.png)" node in the app (which can be only for admin or principal)  when the event is approved by the principal shift these events to another node like "[**APPROVED EVENTS**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTd33.png)". Here you can also notify the requester ( who has created the event ) using FCM ( i advised you to use tokens because then you can notify a specific user )

NOTE: We are using user_uid as key in token node because when we need to get token
of a user ( as example principle )
we will just search for principle id in token node and from there you can get token and notify user in realtime.

**Feel free to ask if something is unclear.**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you simply want to build a chat app using flutter and firebase. I did so following this tutorial https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-a-chat-app-with-flutter-and-firebase-from-scratch-9eaa7f41782e. I know posting links is not the thing you do in a solution but it what I was basically going to write. It also has an extension article for push notifications. You can make it so that if the email is of your pricipal or co ordinator, you can show them the chat option and if you only want to add chat to your principal, instead of getting the stream of users from the users collection(Read the article and you will understand), just give the option of principal and rest is same.